# Understanding Data.Functor.Constant constructor and applicative laws

Tags: haskell, constants, functor, applicative, monoids

I'm confused about Data.Functor.Constant's type constructor and also how it works with applicative.

First the constructor:

When I examine the type of `Constant :: a -> Constant a b`

I see it takes an `a`, but returns a `Constant a b`

Where does the `b` come from and why does it exist?

Secondly, I'm struggling with Applicative:

I understand Constant needs to have a Monoid inside to be an Applicative instance.

A law it must obey is: `pure id <*> Constant x = x`

I thought that was the same as: `Constant id <*> Constant x = x`

but I guess I'm wrong about that since the follow code clearly shows pure acts differently.

```
:t pure id <*> Constant "hello" // Constant [Char] b

:t Constant id <*> Constant "hello" // Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> a0' with actual type `[Char]'

:t pure id <*> Constant reverse //  Constant ([a] -> [a]) b

:t Constant id <*> Constant reverse // Constant ([a] -> [a]) b
```

I see that it only works if `x` is the same monoid unless I use pure. So I'm not sure why pure is working differently. I suspect this has to do with that `b` which is why they're in the same question.

To sum up the two questions:

1. What does `b` do in the Constant constructor?
2. Why does pure work even though the monoids are different inside?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay, so you have this type

```
data Const a b = Const { getConst :: a }
```

Your first question was *"Where does the `b` come from?"*

The answer is that it doesn't come from anywhere. In the same way that you can think of `Maybe b` as a container that holds either 0 or 1 values of type `b`, a `Const a b` is a container that holds exactly 0 values of type `b` (but does definitely hold a value of type `a`).

Your second question was *"Why is it there?"*

Well, sometimes it's useful to have a functor that says it might contain values of type `b`, but actually holds something else (e.g. think of the `Either a b` functor -- the difference is that `Either a b` *might* hold a value of type `b`, whereas `Const a b` definitely doesn't).

Then you asked about the code snippets `pure id <*> Const "hello"` and `Const id <*> Const "hello"`. You thought that these were the same, but they're not. The reason is that the `Applicative` instance for `Const` looks like

```
instance Monoid m => Applicative (Const m) where
  -- pure :: a -> Const m a
  pure _ = Const mempty

  -- <*> :: Const m (a -> b) -> Const m a -> Const m b
  Const m1 <*> Const m2 = Const (m1 <> m2)
```

Since there aren't actually any values having the type of the second parameter, we only have to deal with those having the type of the first parameter, which we know is a monoid. That's why we can make `Const` an instance of `Applicative` -- we need to pull a value of type `m` from somewhere, and the `Monoid` instance gives us a way to make one from nowhere (using `mempty`).

So what happens in your examples? You have `pure id <*> Const "hello"` which must have type `Const String a` since `id :: a -> a`. The monoid in this case is `String`. We have `mempty = ""` for a `String`, and `(<>) = (++)`. So you end up with

```
pure id <*> Const "hello" = Const "" <*> Const "hello"
                          = Const ("" <> "hello")
                          = Const ("" ++ "hello")
                          = Const "hello"
```

On the other hand, when you write `Const id <*> Const "hello"` the left-hand argument has type `Const (a -> a) b` and the right has type `Const String b` and you see that the types don't match, which is why you get a type error.

Now, why is this ever useful? One application is in the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1) library, which lets you use getters and setters (familiar from imperative programming) in a pure functional setting. A simple definition of a lens is

```
type Lens b a = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f a) -> (b -> f b)
```

i.e. if you give it a function that transforms values of type `a`, it will give you back a function that transforms values of type `b`. What is that useful for? Well, let's pick a random function of type `a -> f a` for a particular functor `f`. If we choose the `Identity` functor, which looks like

```
data Identity a = Identity { getIdentity :: a }
```

then if `l` is a lens, the definition

```
modify :: Lens b a -> (a -> a) -> (b -> b)
modify l f = runIdentity . l (Identity . f)
```

provides you with a way to take functions that transform `a`s and turn them into functions that transform `b`s.

Another function of type `a -> f a` we could pass in is `Const :: a -> Const a a` (notice that we've specialized so that the second type is the same as the first). Then the action of the lens `l` is to turn it into a function of type `b -> Const a b`, which tells us that it might contain a `b`, but actually *sneakily* it really contains an `a`! Once we've applied it to something of type `b` in order to get a `Const a b`, we can hit it with `getConst :: Const a b -> a` to pull a value of type `a` out of the hat. So this gives us a way to extract values of type `a` from a `b` -- i.e it's a getter. The definition looks like

```
get :: Lens b a -> b -> a
get l = getConst . l Const
```

As an example of a lens, you could define

```
first :: Lens (a,b) a
first f (a,b) = fmap (\x -> (x,b)) (f a)
```

so that you could open up a GHCI session and write

```
>> get first (1,2)
1
>> modify first (*2) (3,4)
(6,4)
```

which, as you might imagine, is useful in all kinds of situations.

Comment: Good answer, although I think that saying "`Const a b` is *lying* about holding a value of type `b`" is misleading.  Perhaps "`Either a b` might hold a value of type `b` whereas `Const a b` definitely doesn't."?

Comment: @TomEllis Good suggestion, have edited to include it. Would appreciate feedback about my explanation of *lens* as well, this is my first attempt at explaining it.

Comment: I'd just link to SPJ's video explaining it. Well, maybe additionally link to it and say "This is another, fantastic explanation of this."

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. I can't believe I didn't realize Const was partially applied with mempty. That makes a lot of sense. Indeed, lenses are my motivation for looking at this in the first place. Much appreciated.

Comment: The type of `first` should be `Lens (a,b) a`

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: looks like a perfectly decent explanation to me, and apparently exactly what Brian was after!

Comment: You have just explained lenses for me better than wiki, much appreciated